# VB6/ADO: "Method Open of object _Connection failed"

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6, ado

Here's the software involved:

- Visual Basic 6.0
- Windows Vista Business 64-bit
- Microsoft Office 2007
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition 2005 (v3.1)

The error message in its entirety:

```
-2147467259: Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed

Source: Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition OLE DB Provider
```

The connection string being used is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.MOBILE.OLEDB.3.0;Data Source='C:\Path\To\TheDatabase.sdf';
```

The password is provided like so:

```
myDBConnection.Properties("SSCE:Database Password") = "********"
```

The error appears when the "Open" function is called on the ADODB.Connection object.

I've re-installed Windows, re-installed Office, re-installed MSSQL CE 2005, and nothing seems to work. Here's the best part, though: **Some of my coworkers have Windows Vista with this *exact same code*, and when they run it, it doesn't error for them. So this means that something local to this machine is causing this problem.**

If anyone has any suggestions on what I could try to fix this problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Check that MDAC is correctly installed.

Comment: It's Vista, there is no MDAC, it was replaced by Windows DAC when Vista was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, nevermind... turns out the file didn't exist. What a crappy error message. You'd think it would have said "File not found" or something like that.

Ordinarily I would have checked for the file, but the folder was under subversion control so I didn't bother to check. The lesson here: Don't always trust your SVN repo ;)